# Assigning initial values to React properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have the next react code:

```
this.state = {
  colsHiddenStatus: new Map([['rowNumber',true], ['id', false], ['firstName', false], ['lastName', false], ['mobile', false], ['username', false], ['password', false]])    
};  

console.log('???' + this.state.colsHiddenStatus.get['rowNumber']);
```

Any ideas why I am getting:

```
???undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are invoking the `get` incorrectly. It has to be `get()`:

```
console.log('???' + this.state.colsHiddenStatus.get('rowNumber'));
```

You (accidentally) wrote `get[]`, which returns you the object attribute `'rowNumber'` of `get` (via the squared bracket notation) which is possible, since a function is also an object, but it's obviously `undefined` ;-)